# Is it possible to move chrome's title bar icons position?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, icons

Seems unlikely but it wouldn't hurt to ask --
Is it possible to move chrome's title bar icons position, the window resize and close icons?

Such icons' position are different between Linux and Mac, I guess to have more native looks, however recently I need to work in both Mac and Linux, and need to switch between them constantly. I've moved all my Linux's window icons' position to the left, so chrome is the only one behaving inconsistently between the two of my systems.